# Set of all functions from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ taking rational values in partitions with rational endpoints is countable

Tags: general-topology

I have to prove that $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is separable.

I know $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ is a dense countable subset of the interval. I also think I know the general idea of the proof using partitions with rational endpoints and functions which are constant in each element of a given partition.

I have no trouble with the density of that set, however I don't see how to prove it's countable.

Let $S=\{f:[0,1]\mapsto [0,1] \mid \exists 0=a_0<a_1<a_2<\ldots <a_n=1, a_i\in \mathbb{Q} \text { & } \exists q_i\in \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that } f\restriction_{[a_i,a_{i+1})}=q_i\}$. How do I see $S$ is countable?

Comment: The set you have described contains the set of functions $\{x \mapsto t\}_{t \in [0,1]}$, so you can't quite mean that...

Comment: Hint: such an $f$ is determined by $(a_0,\ldots,a_n,q_0,\ldots,q_{n-1}) \in \mathbb Q^{2n-1}$; thus, letting $S_n$ be the subset of your set $S$ for a fixed $n$, we have an injection of $S_n$ into $\mathbb Q^{2n-1}$, and $S = \cup_{n \in \mathbb N} S_n$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thanks, I think I see it now. But since $a_0=0$ and $a_n=1$ then (a_0,\ldots, a_n, q_0, \ldots q_{n-1}) only depends of $2n-1$ values chosen?

Comment: And $S$ is countable since it is a contable union of countable sets, right?

Comment: Note that essentially the same proof holds for $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ and similar large products of separable spaces. But $\mathbb{R}^I$ or $[0,1]^I$ is no longer separable if $|I| > |\mathbb{R}|$, so this is as far as we can go.

Comment: $\mathbb Q^n$ is countable for finite $n$. A countable union of countable sets is countable. So $T=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Q^n$ is countable. ... $S$ is identifiable with a subset of $T$. A subset of a countable set is countable.

Comment: The separability of $[0,1]^{[0,1]} $ is an instance of the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery Theorem.

Comment: @user254665 Which has very similar proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subset $S_n$ of $S$ with $n+1$ domain points $0 = a_0 < a_1 < \ldots a_n =1$ as described, is uniquely determined by a choice of $n-1$ intermediate rationals in $\mathbb{Q}$ and $n$ values $q_0,\ldots q_{n-1}$ from $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ for the values on the intervals. So the mapping that sends $f$ to this tuple, is 1-1.

This then defines an injection from $S_n$ into $(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])^{2n-1}$, and this is a countable set as a *finite* product of countable sets. (should be known, otherwise: biject $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ with $\mathbb{N}$ and apply induction..) So $S_n$ is countable for all $n$.

As $S = \cup_n S_n$ is a countable union of countable sets, it's countable too.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still trying to write every single piece of the proof  from head to toe, and you were great help.

Comment: @3927 After a while you stop doing that. It becomes "obvious". Glad I could help.